# Проектирование баз данных в Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

В каких случаях лучше использовать реляционную модель, а в каких случаях лучше использовать массив на уровне документа для хранения связанной информации об объекте?

Пример: У объекта User есть несколько атрибутов

```
 - Id
 - Name
 - Email
 - Password
 - Role -> {Admin, Super User, etc}
```

Для хранения данных можно создать две таблицы

```
1) tb_users
 - Id
 - Name
 - Email
 - Password

2) tb_users_role
 - Id
 - Id_user
 - role
```

Связь между таблицами для получения инфо о ролях пользователя

```
tb_users.Id <-> tb_users_role.Id_user
```

Второй вариант создать документ
doc_users

```
 - Id
 - Name
 - Email
 - Password
 - Role -> [Admin, Super User, etc] - а действующие роли хранить в виде массива
```

Comment: Если вы всегда достаете юзера из базы вместе с ролями, тогда используйте одно коллекцию, чтобы избежать джоинов на уровне приложения. А если вы достаете юзера, но не пользуетесь ролями, или роли могут меняться независимо от юзера, тогда имеет смысл разделить.

Comment: А в каком случае будет быстрее поиск по роли? Например выбрать всех пользователей с ролью SuperUser. Я на примере хочу разобраться. В реальности модели могут быть сложнее. К примеру - в каких автомобилях установлена конкретная запчасть с конкретным серийным номером.

Comment: При наличии индекса поиск будет быстрее, когда все будет храниться в 1 коллекции, опять же из-за того, что не будет делаться жоин. Запчасть это часть машины, которая сама по себе вряд ли будет использоваться, так что однозначно -> массив или вложенный документ.  Более подробно, когда использовать вложенный документ/массив или отдельную коллекцию можете почитать в оф. документации:https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/#embedded-data-models Там и примеры есть.